# Why are classes not considered completely defined within static data member initializer?

Tags: c++, class, initialization, definition

In the c++ standard it is specified that within the class *member-specification* (class body), the class can be considered *completely-defined*, but not for static data member initializer [class.mem]:

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type (6.9) (or complete type) at the closing } of the
>   *class-specifier*. Within the class *member-specification*, the class is regarded as complete within function
>   bodies, default arguments, *noexcept-specifiers*, and default member initializers (including such things in
>   nested classes). Otherwise it is regarded as incomplete within its own class *member-specification*.

EDIT: This is a citation from N4687, wording has changed but I do not believe the meaning changed.

I was expecting such code to compile:

```
struct enum_like
{
  static constexpr enum_like enum_member{};
};
```

Why such a definition disallowed by the C++ standard?

---

I believe compilers could proceed this way:

1. read member declaration, not definition until class definition closing brace. (Now the compiler has a completely defined class)
2. Analyse static data-member initializer (This way compilers have the constant definition of constexpr members)
3. Analyse other member definitions.

And then resolve recursions for static member intializer as is specified in [decl.init] for non static members!

Comment: You can't define non-static member variables either, since the compiler needs the full definition of the class when defining member variables (static or not). You can *declare* static member variables as well as member functions (static or not) since then all the compiler needs is the symbol, but it doesn't need to know the full definition.

Comment: As for a possible (and practical) reason: How will the compiler know how many bytes of data to reserve for the member variable, if it doesn't have the full definition of the class yet?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Haven't you seen the "static" keyword. Also this code compiles `struct x{static x ax;}; x x::ax{}`. Your comment does not make sense.

Comment: On the example you give in the comment, you only *declare* the static member variable inside the class, you don't *define* it until after the class have been fully defined. It's the *definition* that tells the compiler to reserve memory for the variable.

Comment: Please read again the cited standard paragraph again. Compiler can perform initialization once class is completely-defined!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude My question is in the form "why the c++ standard state that something must happen this way". Your answer is "because the c++ standard disallow it". This too stupid, I am sorry!

Comment: I delete my answer as I see it wasn't what you are actually asking for.  As for a reason why the standard committee chose this to be the case I believe it is because a static class member is just a special global variable.  It's name is scooped to the class but it lives in the global space.  In order to define a variable it needs a complete type at the time of its definition and since there could be more of the class to read once you hit the definition the class is not considered complete.

Answer (score 3):

This rule forbids problematic things like:

```
struct A {
    static constexpr std::size_t N = sizeof(A);
    char buffer[N+2];
};
```